# stackoverflow in multithreaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, stack-overflow

I am facing a desing issue. function 1 and 2 call each other few hundred of times,the recursion is not infinite. while running the program,it meet a overflow condition.setting openmp stacksize is also not working.

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    //some variable private to each thread
    //some processing
    //call function1( array )


}

function1( array ){
     //some variable
    //some processing
    //call function2( array )
    //return


}

function2( array ){
      //some variable
     //some processing
    //if condition fail return
    //else call function1()
    //return
```

}

Comment: Can't you make a single function?

Comment: No,because function1 and 2 call eachother.

Comment: You can use for instance goto statements to replace the calls, so your stack won't grow...

Answer (score 0):

If calling the other function is truly the last thing in each function, you could manually inline function2 into function1 and turn the recursion into a loop:

```
function1(array) {
    while(1) {
        // some variables (from function 1)
        // some processing (from function 1)
        // some variables (from function 2)
        // some processing (from function 2)
        if condition fail break;
        // loop back 'calling' function 1 again
    }
}
```

It may be possible to achieve the same effect by moving the definition of `function2` before `function1` and declaring it inline -- the compiler's optimizer may then be able to inline the function and turn the tail-recursive calls into branches.

If your functions are more complex than you've described (and not tail recursive) then this won't work simply, though you may be able to transform things a bit to make it tail recursive.

Comment: cannot embed function2 in 1. desing criteria

Comment: @user3529728 So the design is to write a piece of code that doesn't work? My advice: find a new job. :)

Comment: @user3529728: There's a term for a design that isn't cognizant of implementation constraints.  It's on the tip of my tongue, of what was it?  Ahh, yes.  "Bad design"

Comment: function2 is complex to add in function1, seperating them make it simple and readible.

Comment: @user3529728 And not working. No matter how simple and readable a piece of code is it does not matter if it is not working. I don't understand why you have a problem with it.

Comment: It's bettter to ask for change in desing.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to have a single function.
In your comment, you say: **«It's not possible because the functions call each other»**.

But this is precisely why you're getting a stack overflow, so this can be considered as bad design...

For what I can see, you do not need separate functions.
You could easily solve the issue with, for instance:

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    // Some variables private to each thread
    // Some processing
    // call function1( array )
}

function1( array )
{
    start:
    {
        // Some variables
        // Some processing
    }

    {
        // Some variables
        // Some processing
        // if condition fail return
        // else goto start
    }
}
```

I know lot's of people says `goto` statements are bad design choices, but in your situation I don't think it's the case... And it will just save your stack space.

Anyway, it will still be better than a non-working piece of code...

Comment: Yeah,many book and sites state goto is bad programming practice but this is the only way i can else it is not possible with out stackoverflow